# Does particle in $x^2$ potential that was found in classically forbidden region gained energy from the measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to wrap my head around the idea of possibility of finding particle in a classically forbidden region in simple harmonic oscillator. The problem is conservation of energy. In the classical settings the total energy is potential energy plus kinetic energy and when this becomes zero, the particle will revert its direction so that its motion remains bounded.

In quantum settings, the solutions of time independent Schroedinger equation for harmonic oscillator $\psi_n(x)\sim H_n(x)e^{-Kx^2}$ these are nonzero in classically forbidden region $E-V\le0$. We prepare a particle so that it is in one of this static states (with $E_n$) and we are trying to measure its position. With enough luck, we will manage to find it in the forbidden region, i.e. at $x_0$ for which $E_n\le V(x_0)$.

Directly after the measurement the particle is in the position eigenstate, i.e. the wave function should be $\psi_\text{after}\sim\delta(x-x_0)$. If I understand it correctly, this position eigenstate should be linear combination of stationary solutions $\psi_n.$ This means, that it should be possible to use linear combinations of $\psi_n(x)$ to write delta function, i.e. $\psi_\text{after}=\sum_n c_n \psi_n$. If this was not possible, we couldn't measure position with arbitrary precision, which seems as a nonsense to me, but I haven't seen mathematical proof that such thing is possible.

Anyway, the expected energy, which before measurement was just $\left<E\right>=E_n$, is after the measurement
$$\left<E\right>=\sum_i |c_i|^2E_i=\int\psi_\text{after}^*\left(\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+V(x)\right)\psi_\text{after} dx=$$$$=V(x_0)+\sum_i |c_i|^2\frac{p^2_i}{2m}\ge V(x_0)\ge E_n$$

So after the measurement, the expected energy of the particle increased. The energy conservation then suggests that the particle gained energy from the measurement itself on average. Is this so?

Comment: That measurements can raise energy is a known issue in quantum theory. We expect that the measurement operator interacting with the system ought to exchange energy.

Comment: All measurements (even classical ones) are irreversible energy transfers, so why are you so surprised that some of the energy in the final state can come from the measurement system itself? The difference between classical mechanics and quantum mechanics is simply that in CM we can ignore this fact (or chalk it up as a measurement error) and in QM we can't. There simply are no particles, by the way, and neither are there any classical systems. Those are just inventions of the human mind to simplify explanations of phenomena. Everything is quantum mechanical.

Comment: Forgetting the SHO, consider an equal superposition of two eigenstates of a hamiltonian with energy eigenvalues $E_1$ and $E_2$. If your measurement takes you to the first,  $\langle E\rangle $ transitions from their average to $E_1$, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, it does. But I don't see the relevance, could you explain more what do you mean?

Comment: It’s but the obverse of your example. Expectation values do not persist.

Comment: Apart from the fact that, as mentioned, expectation values don't persist in measurements, I don't think your calculation is correct. Why would $\int \delta(x-x_0) V(x) \delta(x-x_0) dx$ be $V(x_0)$? Also, there can never be a perfect measurement of the position of a particle since $\delta(x-x_0)$ isn't square-integrable.

Comment: @Tarik $V(x)|\psi>=V(x_0)|\psi>$ when $|\psi>$ is position eigenket. As you say, position eigenket is a delta function which isn't square integrable, but realistic measurement involving collapse to a very narrow (of width $\Delta x$) wave packet $|\psi>=\int \psi_x|x>dx$ instead of exact delta function should produce, in the limit, the same result: $V(x)|\psi>=\int V(x)\psi_x|x>dx=\int [V(x_0)+o(\Delta x)]\psi_x|x>dx=V(x_0) |\psi> + \int o(\Delta x)\psi_x|x>dx\approx V(x_0)|\psi>$